# How to customize join table name AND primary key names in EF Core 6?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-6.0

I wanted to customize the join table and primary key fields in EF Core 6 Migrations using Fluent API when it generates this based on the relationships defined below.

```
public class Product
{   
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the Fluent API in DBContext OnModelCreating

```
 builder.Entity<Part>()
    .HasMany(left => left.Products)
    .WithMany(right => right.Parts)
    .UsingEntity(join => join.ToTable("ProductParts")
    );
```

It creates the many-to-many join table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductParts](
[PartsPartId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductsProductId] [int] NOT NULL
```

I wanted to name the keys just "ProductId" and "PartId" without the prefixes.  Can you name the keys if you're using ToTable and not using an explicit entity join class?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#joining-relationships-configuration